# Does setting img.src cancel previous img.src?

Tags: html, image-processing, signal-processing

In theory:

I have an HTML client listening for notifications from my server. 
As soon as a notification is received, I update my HTML image by setting the `src` to a generic handler.
The image will load.
Now, if another server notification is received before the previous image has finished downloading, is the old `src` property cancelled and the new one takes it place or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an image object, `.src` is just a property that contains a URL.  You can change that property with your code and the last value set in that property is the one that will currently display.  So, if you have code that initially loads one image and then your code changes the `.src` property of the image to a new URL, that new URL will then load.  This will happen whether the previous `.src` property had finished loading or not.

So, yes any previous `.src` property that was in the process of loading will still be replaced by the new `.src` property.